# How to add build react app (js,css) in to the laravel back end server

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I have a front end app (React js) and Back end (Laravel) server.
I build the front end(Reactapp) using `npm run build`.now I got the build folder (`-->static folder-->css`, `js`,`media folder`).

I need to add these static folders (`CSS, js, media`) to the back end (`Laravel server`) and configure. It means when I start `PHP artisan serve` my frond-end react app should be rendered.

how can I add static folders to the back end and configure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @farooq so far I created the react app and got a build file, and I created the Laravel app.

Answer (score 2):

By default laravel comes with `vue.js` .
To use `react.js` in laravel app, You shoudl change from `vue.js` to `react.js` by using the following command .

```
php artisan preset react
```

Then install `npm` in your laravel directory by using ,

```
npm install
```

Push your `react.js` code into `resources/js/` folder. Change the `app.js` contents also. 
For more info, follow the tutorial . 
[laravel-react-tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/react-laravel-application/)

Comment: that's correct. but I don't want to install NPM or adding the package inside the Laravel project. I need how to add a build folder to the Laravel project.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just copy your static folder from your build file and paste it to Laravel Pubilc Dir.

Now we have to find the server.php and change the initial rendering page index.php as index.html.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.html';
```

That's all your front end app(React Js) configure with back end (Laravel)

Comment: I did the same thing as u did. I was able to see the frontend page created using React when I access the URL but the response of index.php displays message inside <noscript> tag. From that page for every API only this index.php returns the message inside <noscript> tag. Do you know how to resolve this?